# Display API data in line charts dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I was having trouble getting `parseInt(res.data[0]['97'].value` to render accurate data from my API call. [0] being the index, and ['97'] being the ID from my API Response. I've updated my code to accept props of {jobId} from my App.js sending the ID to LineChart.js. This allows me to access this ID when it is in a Cycle along with the Title, so that I can say "whatever Title is displaying, get the ID and in LineCharts, match that ID to the data needed for the Line chart."

**Old LineChart.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Scatter } from "react-chartjs-2";

const TotalLineChart = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});
  // const [designHours, setDesignHours] = useState([]);
  // const [designAmount, setDesignAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [subRoughHours, setSubRoughHours] = useState([]);
  // const [subRoughAmount, setSubRoughAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [roughHours, setRoughHours] = useState([]);
  // const [roughAmount, setRoughAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [finishHours, setFinishHours] = useState([]);
  // const [finishAmount, setFinishAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [closeHours, setCloseHours] = useState([]);
  // const [closeAmount, setCloseAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [actualHours, setActualHours] = useState([]);
  // const [actualAmount, setActualAmount] = useState([]);
  
  const chart = () => {
    let designHours = [];
    let designAmount = [];
    let subRoughHours = [];
    let subRoughAmount = [];
    let roughHours = [];
    let roughAmount = [];
    let finishHours = [];
    let finishAmount = [];
    let closeHours = [];
    let closeAmount = [];
    let actualHours = [];
    let actualAmount = [];

    let headers = {
      'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
      'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
      'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

   fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: headers,
     body: JSON.stringify(body)
   }).then(response => response.json())
     .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
          const designHours = parseInt(res.data[0]['89'].value, 10);
          const designAmount = parseInt(res.data[0]['91'].value, 10);
          const subRoughHours = parseInt(res.data[0]['93'].value, 10);
          const subRoughAmount = parseInt(res.data[0]['95'].value, 10);
          const roughHours = parseInt(res.data[0]['97'].value, 10);
          const roughAmount = parseInt(res.data[0]['99'].value, 10);
          const finishHours = parseInt(res.data[0]['105'].value, 10);
          const finishAmount = parseInt(res.data[0]['107'].value, 10);
          const closeHours = parseInt(res.data[0]['477'].value, 10);
          const closeAmount = parseInt(res.data[0]['480'].value, 10);
          const actualHours = parseInt(res.data[0]['479'].value, 10);
          const actualAmount = parseInt(res.data[0]['224'].value, 10);
        }
        setChartData({
          type: 'scatter',
          data: {
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [
                  {x: designHours, y: designAmount },
                  {x: subRoughHours, y: subRoughAmount },
                  {x: roughHours, y: roughAmount },
                  {x: finishHours, y: finishAmount },
                  {x: closeHours, y: closeAmount }
                ],
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)"],
                borderWidth: 4
              }
            ]
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(designHours, designAmount, subRoughHours, subRoughAmount, finishHours, finishAmount, closeHours, closeAmount, actualHours, actualAmount);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Scatter
          data={chartData}
          options={{
            responsive: true,
            title: { text: "", display: true },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 20,
                    beginAtZero: true
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TotalLineChart;
```

**Fixed/Updated LineChart.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Scatter } from "react-chartjs-2";
// import jobId from '../TitleCycle';
// import Title from '../header/Title';

const TotalLineChart = (props) => {
  const {jobId} = props;
  console.log(jobId)
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  const chart = () => {
    let designHours = [];
    let designAmount = [];
    let subRoughHours = [];
    let subRoughAmount = [];
    let roughHours = [];
    let roughAmount = [];
    let finishHours = [];
    let finishAmount = [];
    let closeHours = [];
    let closeAmount = [];
    let actualHours = [];
    let actualAmount = [];

    let headers = {
      "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
      "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
      "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

    const body = {
      from: "bpz99ram7",
      select: [
        3,
        6,
        80,
        81,
        82,
        83,
        86,
        84,
        88,
        89,
        90,
        91,
        92,
        93,
        94,
        95,
        96,
        97,
        98,
        99,
        101,
        103,
        104,
        105,
        106,
        107,
        109,
        111,
        113,
        115,
        120,
        123,
        224,
        225,
        226,
        227,
        228,
        229,
        230,
        231,
        477,
        479,
        480,
        481
      ],
      where: `{3.EX. ${jobId}}`,
      sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
      groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
      options: { skip: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false }
    };

    fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res);
        Object.keys(res.data).map(jobId => {
          const designHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['88'].value, 10);
          const designAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['91'].value, 10);
          const subRoughHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['92'].value, 10);
          const subRoughAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['95'].value, 10);
          const roughHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['96'].value, 10);
          const roughAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['98'].value, 10);
          const finishHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['104'].value, 10);
          const finishAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['107'].value, 10);
          const closeHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['477'].value, 10);
          const closeAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['480'].value, 10);
          const actualHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['479'].value, 10);
          const actualAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['224'].value, 10);

          setChartData({
            type: 'scatter',
              datasets: [
                {
                label: 'TOTAL',
                data: [
                  { x: designHours, y: designAmount },
                  { x: subRoughHours, y: subRoughAmount },
                  { x: roughHours, y: roughAmount },
                  { x: finishHours, y: finishAmount },
                  { x: closeHours, y: closeAmount }
                ],
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: '#4183c4',
                backgroundColor: '#4183c4',
                tension: 0.8,
                spanGaps: true,
                lineTension: 0.5,
                showLine: true,
                fill: false,
                showTooltip: false,
                pointBorderWidth: 1
              },
              {
                label: 'ACTUALS',
                data: [{ x: actualHours, y: actualAmount }],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#e34747',
                backgroundColor: '#e34747',
                borderWidth: 3,
                showTooltip: false
              }
            ],
            options: {
              showAllTooltips: true,
              enabled: true,
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              legend: {
                display: true
              }
            }
          })
          setChartData.addData(chart, label, data); {
            chart.data.labels.push(label);
            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                dataset.data.push(data);
            });
            chart.update();
        }
        
        setChartData.removeData(chart); {
            chart.data.labels.pop();
            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                dataset.data.pop();
            });
            chart.update();
        }
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(
      designHours,
      designAmount,
      subRoughHours,
      subRoughAmount,
      roughHours,
      roughAmount,
      finishHours,
      finishAmount,
      closeHours,
      closeAmount,
      actualHours,
      actualAmount
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Scatter
          data={chartData}
          options={{
            responsive: true,
            title: { text: "Total Project", display: true },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Amount'
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 10,
                    beginAtZero: true
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Hours'
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TotalLineChart;
```

*NOTE how I've added ${jobId} to the API Body, as well as replacing the manually inputted Index in the `parseInt()`*

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.css'
import Title from './components/header/Title'
import TotalLineChart from './components/charts/TotalLineChart'
import RadiantLineChart from './components/charts/RadiantLineChart'
import PlumbingLineChart from './components/charts/PlumbingLineChart'
import SnowmeltLineChart from './components/charts/SnowmeltLineChart'
import HVACLineChart from './components/charts/HVACLineChart'
import GasPipeLineChart from './components/charts/GasPipeLineChart'
import FixturesLineChart from './components/charts/FixturesLineChart'
// import TitleCycle from './components/TitleCycle'
// import Logo from './components/Logo';

let headers = {
  "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
  "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
  "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXX",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

function App() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  // Fetch all data, all jobs
  useEffect(() => {
      function fetchData() {
          let body = {
              from: "bpz99ram7",
              select: [3, 6, 40],
              where: "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}",
              sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
              groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
              options: { skip: 0, top: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false },
          };
          fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(({ data }) => setAllData(data));
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);

// Cycle through the jobIds and indexes
useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
        () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % allData.length),
        5000 // 5 seconds.
    );
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, [allData]);
console.log(allData)
console.log(index)
// Calculate info based on index
const jobId = allData[index]?.['3']?.value || 291; // Default 291
const title = allData[index]?.['6']?.value || 'Default Title'; 
console.log(jobId)
  return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="flexbox-container">
          <div className="Logo">
          {/* <Logo /> */}
         {/* </div> */}
        <div className="App">
          <Title title = {title}/>
        </div>
        <div className="TopChart">
          <TotalLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
        </div>
        <div className="FirstRowContainer">
          <RadiantLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <PlumbingLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <FixturesLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
        </div>
        <div className="SecondRowContainer">
          <SnowmeltLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <HVACLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <GasPipeLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
        </div> 
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*App.js takes the field ID and cycles it along with the Title in a duration of 5 seconds each, then sends that data to LineChart.js to be used at the same time with corresponding data.*

**UPDATE**: Able to display dynamically by using props with IDs needed, and using those in each api call to get specific data based on the Title Displaying:

**App.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.css'
import Title from './components/header/Title'
import TotalLineChart from './components/charts/TotalLineChart'
import RadiantLineChart from './components/charts/RadiantLineChart'
import PlumbingLineChart from './components/charts/PlumbingLineChart'
import SnowmeltLineChart from './components/charts/SnowmeltLineChart'
import HVACLineChart from './components/charts/HVACLineChart'
import GasPipeLineChart from './components/charts/GasPipeLineChart'
import FixturesLineChart from './components/charts/FixturesLineChart'
// import TitleCycle from './components/TitleCycle'
// import Logo from './components/Logo';

let headers = {
  "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
  "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
  "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXXX",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Retry-After": 120000
};

function App() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  // Fetch all data, all jobs
  useEffect(() => {
      function fetchData() {
          let body = {
              from: "bpz99ram7",
              select: [3, 6, 40],
              where: "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}",
              sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
              groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
              options: { skip: 0, top: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false },
          };
          fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(({ data }) => setAllData(data));
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);

// Cycle through the jobIds and indexes
useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
        () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % allData.length),
        5000 // 5 seconds.
    );
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, [allData]);
// console.log(allData)
// console.log(index)
// Calculate info based on index
const jobId = allData[index]?.['3']?.value || '291'; // Default 291
const title = allData[index]?.['6']?.value || 'Default Title'; 
// console.log(jobId)
  return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="flexbox-container">
          <div className="Logo">
          {/* <Logo /> */}
         {/* </div> */}
        <div className="App">
          <Title title = {title} />
        </div>
        <div className="TopChart">
          <TotalLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
        </div>
        <div className="FirstRowContainer">
          {/* <RadiantLineChart jobId = {jobId} /> */}
          <PlumbingLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
          <FixturesLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
        </div>
        <div className="SecondRowContainer">
          <SnowmeltLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
          <HVACLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
          <GasPipeLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
        </div> 
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**LineChart.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Scatter } from "react-chartjs-2";
// import jobId from '../TitleCycle';
// import Title from '../header/Title';

function TotalLineChart(props) {
  const { jobId } = props;
  // console.log(`${jobId}`)
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  const chart = () => {
    let designHours = [];
    let designAmount = [];
    let subRoughHours = [];
    let subRoughAmount = [];
    let roughHours = [];
    let roughAmount = [];
    let finishHours = [];
    let finishAmount = [];
    let closeHours = [];
    let closeAmount = [];
    let actualHours = [];
    let actualAmount = [];

    let headers = {
      "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
      "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
      "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXX",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-ratelimit-reset": 10000,
      "Retry-After": 30000
    };
    // useEffect(() => {
    //   function fetchData() {
      const body = {
        from: "bpz99ram7",
        select: [
          3,
          88,
          91,
          92,
          95,
          96,
          98,
          104,
          107,
          224,
          477,
          479,
          480,
        ],
        where: `{3.EX. ${ jobId }}`,
        sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
        groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
        options: { skip: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false }
      };
      fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      })
    //   }
    //   fetchData();
    // }, [])

      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res);
        Object.keys(res.data).map(jobId => {
          designHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['88'].value, 10);
          designAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['91'].value, 10);
          subRoughHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['92'].value, 10);
          subRoughAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['95'].value, 10);
          roughHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['96'].value, 10);
          roughAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['98'].value, 10);
          finishHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['104'].value, 10);
          finishAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['107'].value, 10);
          closeHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['477'].value, 10);
          closeAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['480'].value, 10);
          actualHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['479'].value, 10);
          actualAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['224'].value, 10);

          setChartData({
            type: 'scatter',
            redraw: true,
              datasets: [
                {
                label: 'TOTAL',
                data: [
                  { x: designHours, y: designAmount },
                  { x: subRoughHours, y: subRoughAmount },
                  { x: roughHours, y: roughAmount },
                  { x: finishHours, y: finishAmount },
                  { x: closeHours, y: closeAmount }
                ],
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: '#4183c4',
                backgroundColor: '#4183c4',
                tension: 0.8,
                spanGaps: true,
                lineTension: 0.5,
                showLine: true,
                fill: false,
                showTooltip: false,
                pointBorderWidth: 1
              },
              {
                label: 'ACTUALS',
                data: [{ x: actualHours, y: actualAmount }],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#e34747',
                backgroundColor: '#e34747',
                borderWidth: 3,
                showTooltip: false
              }
            ],
            options: {
              showAllTooltips: true,
              enabled: true,
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              legend: {  
                display: true
              }
            }
          })
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Scatter 
        // ref={(reference) => this.chartReference = reference } 
          data={chartData}
          options={{
            title: { text: "Total Project", display: false },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: '$ AMOUNT'
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 10,
                    beginAtZero: true
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'HOURS'
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TotalLineChart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying all kind of weird radixes for your parseInt method, I assume all of your values are just base 10, even if not with a quick test the radix argument only goes up till 36, so if you remove that it should work.

Also you are pushing the same value to a lot of different arrays, seems like you need to specify the value in the dataObject you want to push and not just value, otherwise 1 array would be enough.

Comment: Ok so this is obviously where I am confused so I apologize. I'm attempting to pull those field ID's from my API call and having it assigned to those values, so I can create the x and y axis in the fashion shown above.

Comment: instead of looping through an array containing 1 item, which is redundent. take your pushes outside of the loop and then call `parseInt(res.data[0]['3'].value)` where the number 3 between quotes is the id you want, and ofc dont try to parseInt String fields

Comment: Ok this is working to show my values! I was thinking this way to get all those values for one Job at a time and only displaying that job on the line chart.

Comment: how would you recommend me getting all at the same time? I have a separate component that is cycling through job names on a set duration, and I'd like these to show up on the line chart based on which title is displaying